# Сохранение сессий в express

Tags: node.js, сессия, express

Подскажите, как правильно сохранять сессию в NodeJs. Ниже привел содержимое файла app.js

**Обновление**

В файле app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var SessionStore = require('express-mysql-session');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'theme'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.cookieParser());

var options = {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 3000,
    user: 'nodejs',
    password: 'c5c58f',
    database: 'nodejs'
}

app.use(session({
    key: 'session_cookie_name',
    secret: 'session_cookie_secret',
    store: new SessionStore(options)
}))

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    req.session.number = req.session.number + 1 || 1;
    console.log(req.session.number)
})

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'number' of undefined

В чем может быть ошибка, я уже вторую неделю не могу решить эту проблему, задавал тот же вопрос на Toster, решения не нашлось. Не ужели в NodeJs нельзя реализовать сохранение сессии в БД MySql. Везде приводят пример с сохранением в MongoDB, может действительно NodeJs на столько ограничен.

Делал по [этому уроку](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3xy6uh8rcI&feature=youtu.be).

Comment: https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/examples/auth/app.js

Comment: Почему при простом сохранении сессии 
req.session.user = 'user';
Мне пишет TypeError: Cannot set property 'user' of undifined

Comment: Скорее всего, вы не подключили сессии, приведите код.

    var session = require('express-session')
    var app = express()
    app.use(session({secret: 'keyboard cat'}))

это есть в начале приложения?

Comment: У вас, наверное, сильно устаревший урок, во-первых, express.session уже session, во-вторых, https://github.com/chill117/express-mysql-session вроде бы работает, в отличие от connect-mysql-session

Comment: Спасибо, завтра попробую!

Comment: К сожалению, ничего не вышло, перефразировал свой вопрос, выложил полный код.

Comment: ещё раз - у вас устаревший express

http://scotch.io/bar-talk/expressjs-4-0-new-features-and-upgrading-from-3-0 

ваш код на express 4.0 не работает 

> Error: Most middleware (like bodyParser) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот так работает, обратите внимание на предупреждения при старте, я не стал исправлять, но в продакшене надо следовать этим инструкциям:

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var SessionStore = require('express-mysql-session');
var http = require('http');
var connect = require('connect');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'theme'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(connect.bodyParser());
app.use(connect.favicon());
app.use(connect.logger('dev'));
app.use(connect.json());
app.use(connect.urlencoded());
app.use(connect.methodOverride());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(connect.cookieParser());

var options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'test'
}

app.use(session({
    key: 'session_cookie_name',
    secret: 'session_cookie_secret',
    store: new SessionStore(options)
}))

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("aaa");
    req.session.number = req.session.number + 1 || 1;
    console.log(req.session.number)
    res.end("You saw this "+req.session.number.toString()+" times");
    next();
})

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "sample1",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "connect": "^2.25.7",
    "express": "^4.8.5",
    "express-mysql-session": "^0.2.0",
    "express-session": "^1.7.6"
  }
}
```

сложите эти два файла в новую директорию, запустите

```
 npm install
```

исправьте пароли к базе данных, потом -

```
 node app.js
```

перейдите на http://localhost:3000

перестаньте смотреть видеоуроки.

Comment: Дааааа, работает, ОГРОМНЕЙШЕЕ СПАСИБО !!!

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = express();

app.use(session({
  secret: 'your secret here',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  key: 'jsessionid',
  store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
}));

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
   // console.log("serializeUser", user);
   done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
   User.findById(id).exec(function (err, user) {
     // console.log("deserializeUser", user);
     done(err, user);
   });
});

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.post('/api/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function (req, 
res, next) {
  res.cookie('user', JSON.stringify(req.user._id));
  res.send(req.user);
});

app.post('/api/logout', function (req, res, next) {
   req.logout();
   res.clearCookie('user');
   res.send(200).end();
});

app.get('/api/user', function (req, res, next) {
   if (req.user)
      res.send(req.user);
   else
      res.send(false);
});
```

И надо не забыть подключить все библиотеки.